# Measuring coverage for each test with unittest and coverage.py

Tags: python, python-unittest, coverage.py

I’m trying to measure code coverage per test case (it’s a fun project, I couldn’t really provide a use case). For that I have my custom result class (excerpt):

```
class CoverageResult(unittest.result.TestResult):
    def __init__(self, coverage_sources=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if coverage_sources:
            self.coverage = coverage.coverage(branch=True, include=coverage_sources)
        else:
            self.coverage = None

    def startTest(self, test):
        if self.coverage:
            self.coverage.start()
        super(CoverageResult, self).startTest(test)

    def stopTest(self, test):
        if self.coverage:
            self.coverage.stop()
            self.coverage.report()
            self.coverage.erase()

        super(CoverageResult, self).stopTest(test)
```

This works fine, and prints out the coverage report for each test. However, I’d like to only save it (for processing later), and display a summarized report at the end of the test run. For this, I modified the `stopTest()` method and added a property:

```
def stopTest(self, test):
    if self.coverage:
        self.coverage.stop()
        # self.test_data is a dict with tests as a key, and contains timing information and stuff for each test.
        self.test_data[test]['coverage'] = self.coverage.data
        # This is needed so I don’t erase the result I just saved
        self.coverage.data = coverage.CoverageData()
        self.coverage.erase()

@property
def coverage_data(self):
    for test, data in self.test_data:
        self.coverage.data.update(d['coverage'])

    return self.coverage
```

Now if I run my tests and at the end print the result with `result.coverage_data.report()`, I get nothing but an exception:

```
coverage.misc.CoverageException: No data to report.
```

I’m aware that I could save per-test coverage data to files on the disk (or even a file-like object like `StringIO`), and later combine them into one, but how can I pass it to a `Coverage` instance so it can generate a report from it?

Comment: You are doing some unusual things here (mainly re-initializing coverage.data in stopTest).  At a glance, it seems like it should work.  Please open an issue on the coverage.py issue tracker, with a link to code I can run, and we'll get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Thanks, I will. I know it's unusual, but if you have any other idea on how to do it, I'm open to ideas :)

Comment: It's not so unusual, lots of people want something very similar: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201612/who_tests_what.html

Comment: This pretty much covers my idea, except I don’t necessarily want to display report on a per-test basis (although I’d like to store it, but I could already figure that out). The report should be done on the combined data. Now on to that bug report…

Comment: If you aren't going to report on them separately, why capture them separately?

Comment: Sorry, bad wording. I don’t want to report it with `cov.report()`, but I do want to store it for analysis later.

Comment: I'm interested in what kinds of analysis you would do later.

Comment: I’m mainly interested if some of the tests actually test what they should. In my previous company there were tests that were intended to test a function, but missed a branch or two. These other branches had coverage, because they were unintentionally ran by other tests.

Comment: It turned out this was impossible with (or a bug in) Coverage.py 4.2. It works perfectly fine in 4.3.